# React Prop-Types not detected ESLint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

I have this on my react page:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

...then

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.myfunction();
  }
```

...and finally:

```
MyComponent.PropTypes = {
  myfunction: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Why does ESLine still complain with:

*"ESLint: 'myfunction' is missing in props validation"* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using lower-case for your propTypes declaration:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  myfunction: PropTypes.func,
};
```

The difference here is that `PropTypes` (captial "P") is your node package, but `propTypes` (lowercase) is the name of the object inside your component.

---

#### Demo

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.myFunction();
  }
  render() {
    return (<p>hello</p>);
  }
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  myfunction: PropTypes.func,
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp myFunction={() => {console.log("foo bar")}} />, document.getElementById("myApp"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp"></div>
```